# Pull DIV from separate page and update DIV in current page

Tags: ajax

I've got a simple one but haven't been able to find an example of a solution that fits exactly what I'm asking. Sorry in advance if this is a repeat.

From my navigation menu, I want each link to reference a specific DIV in a separate page and then pull that DIV and replace the content in the current page.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
..and so on
</ul>
```

Elsewhere in the page:

```
<div id="displayContent">Content refreshes onClick. Previous content fades out, fresh content fades in.</div>
```

Separate page (content.php):

```
<div id="about">About content</div>
<div id="contact">Contact content</div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear - What do you mean by other page? Is this a different tab in your browser? Is this a popup Screen? Is this a different frame on the same page? Is this a different section that has been loaded using Ajax?

Comment: Sorry Julian, what I mean is that I will have a different page on my server that will act as only a source for the content to be displayed (ie content.php). Visitors will arrive at index.php and when the click one of the links in the navigation menu, index.php will call upon content.php and pull in only the specified div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with brhea, a question is a bit unclear.

If I understood well you're looking for something like this?

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

(click car names to see it in action)

OR with jQuery like this:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Yes, exactly like that link. However I notice that it was updated in '05 so I would be open to recommendations that might take advantage of more current standards.

Comment: I've added another link, you can do this even more easily with jQuery. I guess other frameworks have an equivalent too.